# Why are these double notes labeled 'contrary motion'?

Tags: theory

In my PDF version of Slonimsky's Thesaurus, there's a section called 'Double Notes in Contrary Motion' on page 215. Can anyone explain why he is calling these contrary motion? To me, apart from the very last example no. 343 (at the bottom of page 217), they all seem to be either similar or parallel motion. I'm sure I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: we need a picture, could you please provide one?

Comment: I don't know  whether we have the same sheet?
do you mean this pdf: http://www.lapetitedistribution.org/archive/Nicolas_Slonimsky.pdf
answer: in each line p. 215 is at least one group of 4 - 6  16th in countrary motion ...

Answer (score 6):

Each hand plays 3rds in similar motion.   The contrary motion is between the two hands, as marked.  It's not ALL contrary motion, but there's a lot of it[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKHy2.png)